# Running StorageOS on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to use StorageOS for dynamic volume provisioning on a self-hosted K8s cluster `v1.11.1`.

The StorageOS [docs](https://docs.storageos.com/docs/platforms/kubernetes/install/1.10) offer two options, one using the new CSI, the other using the StorageOS volume driver built into K8s. I first tried the CSI-based approach, but that failed. From what I could gather, getting CSI to work in K8s requires several preparatory steps ([according to this reference](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/Setup.html)), which seemed too advanced, so I tried to go the non-CSI route.

So I followed the docs and got the pods, services etc. created, but the pods are restarting all the time. A describe turns up the error:

> Liveness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 500

Looking at the logs, I find tons of these:

```
time="2018-09-12T12:14:20Z" level=info msg="not first cluster node, joining first node" action=create address=192.168.34.201 category=etcd host=worker21 module=cp target=192.168.33.101
time="2018-09-12T12:14:20Z" level=error msg="failed to join existing cluster" action=create category=etcd endpoint="192.168.33.101,192.168.33.201,192.168.34.201,192.168.34.202" error="Get http://192.168.33.101:5705/v1/members: dial tcp 192.168.33.101:5705: connect: connection refused" module=cp
```

Since there is mention of `etcd`, it seems StorageOS cannot find it. I was assuming that it would use the `etcd` of my cluster. Unfortunately, I couldn't find any instructions to set up `etcd` specifically for StorageOS. On the other hand, the port 5705 is the StorageOS REST API, so maybe that isn't even the problem. Any pointers welcome!

Comment: can you post more info, like `kubectl describe pod <podname>`? What pods are failing?

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out that reading the readme helped. ;-)
The scripts by default try to deploy the StorageOS daemonset on all nodes - including the master(s). If those are configured to not accept workloads, the whole deployment will fail.
Solution is to manually maintain the JOIN variable in the deploy-storageos script.